# MYSQL User Set Permissions host from SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh

How do you set a users host permission via SSH for MySql?

I've managed to accidentally set the wrong domain/ip for my root user in WebMin > MySQL Server permissions.  Like I went into hosts to allow remote access and put the wrong address.  Now even Webmin cannot get into he database with the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Login to server via SSH.

Use following command to enter mysql:

```
mysql --skip-grant-tables -u root -p
```

`skip-grant-tables` will cause mysql to abandon privilege system for this session.

Then use grant command to grant any privilege to your root user:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'my-host-or-ip'
```